# Swift segue is segueing to the first controller when the identifier is specified

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, segue

Thanks for your time. I have a fully functional application there is this one segue that when selected it segues to the starting controller. This happens only when the app is installed and its the first time calling this segue. it doesnt happen if you close and open the app and it never happens again after that.

**Scenario:**

1. Login Successful (Segues to TabController)
2. Then on the 3rd Tab I have cells and when the cell is clicked it segues back to the LoginController (Should Segue to DiscoverController)
3. This is done with a `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segDiscover", sender: nil)`
4. The discoverController is never hit
5. The LoginController `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` is fired

I use the method `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

I have debugged in the simulator and the methods fire and follow through right until it leaves the controller and hits the LoginController

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The code below is the `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

**Code Snip-it**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 

    if segue.identifier == "segDiscover"{

      if(self._refresh.isRefreshing == false){

        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBarHeight.constant = 0

        self.searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar)
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        let Controller = segue.destination as! DiscoverVC

      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: To be clear you want to go to Discover controller instead of LoginController ?

Comment: Yes. It does work. However when the app is installed for the first time the first click that activates that segue goes into the prepare and then after that it goes to login, However this never occurs again after the first click